# Optimal BitmapLRU Cache Size Android 1/8th of total memory or three screens of memory?

Tags: android

What is the optimal BitmapLRU **image** cache size on Android for caching images? I am targeting sdk 2.3.5+ basically 10+ devices. Currently I am taking the larger amount of these two calculations as shown below.  Is 1/8th a safe pct to avoid out of memory errors?

Here is how I am calculating it now:

```
private static int calculateImageCacheSize(Context ctx)
{
    // Gets the dimensions of the device's screen
    DisplayMetrics dm = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;

    // Assuming an ARGB_8888 pixel format, 4 bytes per pixel
    int size = screenWidth * screenHeight * 4;

    // 3 bitmaps to store therefore multiply bitmap size by 3
    int cacheSize = size * 3;

    int cachePercentOfMemory = getPercentageOfTotalMemory(8);
    int retCacheSize = cacheSize;
    if (retCacheSize < cachePercentOfMemory)
        retCacheSize = cachePercentOfMemory;
    return retCacheSize;
}

public static int getPercentageOfTotalMemory(int divider)
{
     final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
     final int cacheSize = maxMemory / divider;
     return cacheSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no one "right" answer, and really depends what your app is doing. If it does lots network connections, have complex data structures, decodes lots of Bitmaps...etc, then the code itself would consume quite a bit of memory and setting image cache size to 1/8 should be reasonable. However if your app is quite simplistic you can probably raise the amount of memory allocated for caching.

So if you are really concerned about it, the only way to know is to have tests testing your app and see which configuration works the best for this particular app.